# Add additional properties to the output json

Tags: mongodb

There is a collection of User

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T09:34:14.651Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:14.119Z"),
    "name" : "John",
    "email" : "test1@gmail.com",
    "groupsFavorite" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a0d45db8af3a91847b7cf96")
    ],
    "groups" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a0d45db8af3a91847b7cf96"), 
        ObjectId("5a0d45e18af3a91847b7cf97")
    ],
    "__v" : 3
}
```

There is a collection of Groups

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d45db8af3a91847b7cf96"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:31.815Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:31.815Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95"),
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-1",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d45e18af3a91847b7cf97"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:37.005Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:37.005Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95"),
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-2",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d5cb0cd59342da943d55a"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T09:38:56.912Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T09:38:56.912Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a0d5c48cd59342da943d559"),
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-3",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

There is a method that returns groups of a particular user.
It is necessary to add these data to the new property of `favorite: true` or `false` for building a table.

For example:

```
{
    "_id" :"5a0d45db8af3a91847b7cf96",
    "updatedAt" : "2017-11-16T08:01:31.815Z",
    "createdAt" : "2017-11-16T08:01:31.815Z",
    "userId" : "5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95",
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-1",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "favorite": "true"
},
{
    "_id" : "5a0d45e18af3a91847b7cf97",
    "updatedAt" : "2017-11-16T08:01:37.005Z",
    "createdAt" : "2017-11-16T08:01:37.005Z",
    "userId" : "5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95",
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-2",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "favorite": "false"
},
{
    "_id" : "5a0d5cb0cd59342da943d55a",
    "updatedAt" : "2017-11-16T09:38:56.912Z",
    "createdAt" : "2017-11-16T09:38:56.912Z",
    "userId" : "5a0d5c48cd59342da943d559",
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-3",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "favorite": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` operator for checking the `_id` and `userId` fields in "User" collection. And also for determining it is in or not, you can use `$eq` operator.

```
db.getCollection('Groups').aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "User",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "groupsFavorite",
        as: "FavoriteByGrp"
      }
   }
  ,{
      $lookup:
      {
        from: "User",
        localField: "userId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "FavoriteByUsr"
      }
   }
  ,{
       "$project":
       {
           _id:1,
           updatedAt:1,
           createdAt:1,
           userId:1,
           title:1,
           slug:1,
           description:1,
           favorite: 
           { 
               "$cond": 
               { 
                   if: { "$eq": [ "$FavoriteByGrp._id", "$FavoriteByUsr._id" ] }, 
                   then: "true", 
                   else: "false" 
               } 
           }
       }

   }
 ])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d45db8af3a91847b7cf96"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:31.815Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:31.815Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95"),
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-1",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "favorite" : "true"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d45e18af3a91847b7cf97"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:37.005Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T08:01:37.005Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95"),
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-2",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "favorite" : "false"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d5cb0cd59342da943d55a"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T09:38:56.912Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-16T09:38:56.912Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a0d5c48cd59342da943d559"),
    "title" : "New title",
    "slug" : "new-title-3",
    "description" : "Lorem",
    "favorite" : "false"
}
```

Comment: According to your example, I got the whole list of groups, and not for a specific user, and besides all the `favorite` is `false`

Comment: the same thing is only now everything is `true` )))
I'm done of course, but this is a biting solution:

```
await Group.find({ userId })
  .lean()
  .exec((err, groups) => {
    groups.map(group => {
      user.groupsFavorite.forEach(favGroup => {
        if (String(favGroup) === String(group._id)) {
          group.favorite = true
        } else {
          group.favorite = false
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Is it possible to update the question data with your test data or at least similar data? Because I am getting the above result when I run the script.

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry. The correct name of the collections is `users` and `groups`.
According to your example, I get a list with the included favorite field, but I still get the entire list of groups, and not for a specific user. User in example has only one favorite group.

Comment: it worked out, I added to your example another `$match: {
'userId': ObjectId("5a0d45ca8af3a91847b7cf95")
}`. Thanks for the replies, now I have a bit more understanding of mongodb ))

Comment: Yes, $match operator filters your result. But at your sample result, you are listing all user, that's why I did not add $match operator to the script.